# Resolve SAS Macro Variable in Select Statement

Tags: sas

I have a field that needs to be selected from one table in certain cases and another table in other cases.  I'm trying to use a Macro Variable to resolve which table to select the field from but keep getting an error.

In the scenario below, the variable TableValue has a value of 'abc' based on conditions determined earlier in my program.  The variable is used within the SELECT statement to reference a table with that alias:

```
SELECT 
    &TableValue..type as ITEM_TYPE
FROM 
    rca.items abc
    left join rca2.items abcd on rca2.ItemNum = rca.ItemNum
```

I am having trouble resolving the above variable, I am receiving the following error:

```
ORACLE prepare error: ORA-22806: not an object or REF. SQL statement: SELECT 
       'abc'.type
```

Any help would be appreciated, I suspect it has to do with the single quotes but haven't been able to replace etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the macro variable TableValue has a value with quotes in it: `'abc'` the answer would be to remove the quotes.

To debug this, get the program working with no macro variables:

```
SELECT 
    abc.type as ITEM_TYPE
FROM 
    rca.items abc
    left join rca2.items abcd on rca2.ItemNum = rca.ItemNum
```

Then after that is working, replace `abc` with a macro variable reference that will resolve to `abc`.